# Dagger 2 not generateing components on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have created a Java application with Eclipse and I'm using Maven for the package management. Several days ago I was able to configure my application to work with Dagger 1 (adding the dependencies to the pom file, enabling the annotation processing and adding the dagger, dagger-compile, javax and javawriter jars to the Factory Path). After several discussion with my colleagues we decided to use Dagger 2. I tried to migrate the Dagger 1 implementation to Dagger 2 by following the [Dagger 2 documentation](http://google.github.io/dagger/dagger-1-migration.html), but it did not work.

For some unexplained reason the `@Component` class with the `Dagger` prefix is not generated.

Because of this I decided to try the [Dagger 2 Coffee sample](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee).

I created a new Eclipse Java project, converted it to Maven, added the sample code and the Dagger 2 dependencies to the pom file:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
```

My build failed with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee cannot be resolved
```

I extracted the `Coffee` component interface to a separate file (named `Coffee.java`) and tried again but I got the same error.

I removed the Factory Path jars from Dagger 1, but the result was still the same. If I try to add the Dagger 2 jars, I get the **Multiple problems have occurred** window with the following error text 
`Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'dagger'.
com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap`

I found out that the problem occurs when I add the `dagger-compiler` jar.

If I remove every jar from the Factory Path the build still fails.

I tried to find the `DaggerCoffee` file, that should be automatically generated but I couldn't find it.

How can I use Dagger 2 with Eclipse? I red the documentation several times and spend a day researching this, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a lot of trials and errors I finally managed to configure Dagger 2 in Eclipse. I went to Project => Properties => Java Compiler => Annotation Processing => Factory Path and added the jars for `dagger`, `dagger-compiler`, `dagger-producers`, `javax.inject-1` and `guava-18.0`. The `guava-18.0` jar is the tricky part. I had another dependency that used an older version of `guava-14.0.1` and it was added first to the `pom.xml` file. This resulted in the older version of `guava` downloaded to my maven dependencies, but it did not work with Dagger 2.

So the moral of the story is that you should always check the dependency versions.

Comment: I also had to enable annotation processing within "Java Compiler" -> "Annotation Processing"

Answer (score 17):

Current Eclipse IDE (2022-12 and newer):

- Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Annotation Processing:
  Select "Automatically configure JDT APT"

Older Eclipse versions:

It also works using m2e-apt. No need to add custom libs:

- Install m2e-apt (not needed for newer eclipse versions)
- Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Annotation Processing:
  Select "Automatically configure JDT APT"
- Update the maven project

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Jotschi said, I also needed to add the following to my pom.  Note the JDK version number needs to be set, as the default Maven uses is v1.5 and annotation code generation was added in v1.6:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: I tried this and ran into a lot of problems one of which was that i was omitting the version. You need to specify the version otherwise eclipse will not be able to map the configuration for m2e. Additionally I got less problems while using Eclipse Neon instead of Mars.

Answer (score 0):

I also found getting dagger v2.8 to work in Eclipse 4.6.1 (Neon) with JDK 1.7 a bit of a challenge.  After installing m2e-apt and enabling annotation processing in both "Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Annotation Processing" and "project/Properties -> Maven -> Annotation Processing", I still had to add the plugins text to my pom.xml file.  Here's the snippet of the POM file that worked for me:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>  
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```